# One panel overlapping on another on window resize

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have on Ext Window on which I am using border layout and placed two two panel in `west` and `center`. Now problem is when I am trying to resize the window center panel is getting overlap on west panel. Any solution fro this.

```
Ext.define('ABC.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',
    layout: 'border',

    items: [
    {
        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        scroll: 'y',
        frame: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        scrollable: true,
        flex: .18,
        split: false,
        items: [Some Tabs]
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        frame: true,
        scrollable: true,
        scroll: 'y',    
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [Some Grid]
    }]
});
```

Code for window.

```
H1 = new Ext.IframeWindow({
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        title: 'Molecular Biomarkers',
                        closable: true,
                        constrain : true,
                        src: Some Path
                    });
```

Comment: If you want to use only two items in above panel, then why dont you use Columns layout.Check this link, it contains example for column layout:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html